# Поиск из массива , если есть убираем если нет добавляем

Tags: javascript, массивы, for

Я хочу сделать так, чтобы цикл for искал из массива. Если на массиве есть совпадающий значение то убираем его , а если нет то добавляем . Но хочу добавить 1 раз а не много.

```js
let names = ['Milk','Apple','Juice','Robot'];
function findWith(Name) {
    let namesLength = names.length;
    for(let i = 0; i < namesLength; i++) {
        if(Name === names[i]) {
        //    Если есть то показываем его или удаляем его
        console.log(names)
        } else {
            // Если нет то добавляем его  ОДИН РАЗ !
            names.push(Name)
        }
    }
}
// У меня не работает
findWith('Cat') // Нужно добавить
findWith('Milk') // Нужно удалить или показать
```

Comment: используй [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)  и не парься

Comment: так сет не удалит имеющиеся

Comment: @Эникейщик сначала удалить, а потом использовать Set. 2n

Comment: @Эникейщик чё эт? если использовать сразу Set, то можно использовать встроенные методы проверку has и удаление delete.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский   Можете лучше показать ?

Comment: @Эникейщик  Можете лучше показать ?

Comment: Ссылка на документацию в первом же комментарии

Comment: @WhiteMoon а значения уникальные или могут быть несколько раз? Тогда удалять все?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Я имел виду изменить мою код

Comment: @splash58
Функция одно и тоже , но значение уникалные

Answer (score 2, accepted):

можно пройти по массиву, прервать функциию, если значение нашлось,  и добавить только, если не встретилось нужного значения

```js
let names = ['Milk','Apple','Juice','Robot'];
function findWith(Name) {
    let namesLength = names.length;
    for(let i = 0; i < namesLength; i++) {
        if(Name === names[i]) {
        //    Если есть то показываем его или удаляем его
           console.log(names)
           return
        } 
    }
    // Если нет то добавляем его  ОДИН РАЗ !
    names.push(Name)
}
// У меня не работает
findWith('Cat') // Нужно добавить
findWith('Milk') // Нужно удалить или показать
```

Comment: Вот и я этого хотел спасибо большое брат !